# Combining similar signals in timeseries

Tags: python, python-3.x, signal-processing

Let's say I have a signal that goes like this. I've already put it through the rounds of fitting, and I can more easily manage the signal now.

But for whatever reason, there are some tiiiiny differences that I can't seem to eliminate.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


a = [0.5]*20
b = [0.4]*20
c = [0.503]*20
d = [0.4]*20

signal = pd.Series(np.concatenate([a,b,c,d]))

plt.figure(figsize = (7,3))
plt.plot(signal, color = "firebrick")
plt.axhline(0.5, linestyle = ":")
plt.show()

# Identify the four different intensities, so they can be grouped
id = signal.transform(lambda x: (abs(x.diff()) > 0).cumsum())
```

I'm thinking a solution could be to line up all the signals from low to high
`[0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.503]`

And then go through them, while ignoring tiny differences e.g. `0.010`, so

`id = signal.transform(lambda x: (abs(x.diff()) > 0.010).cumsum())`

Then I would correctly identify only 2 different intensities. For the tiny discrepancy I could just take the mean or the median. It doesn't really make a difference. What matters is that I don't count more than 2 different intensities.

How would I do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What is your question? What is your desired output?

Comment: @pault essentially I would like to correct the overshooting of the fit, so that the means of 0.503 and 0.5 become aligned to the same value (mean, median, smallest, doesn’t matter), at the same indices as the original data. Does that make sense?

Comment: What about thresholding the series? For example, threshold by the mean and compute median values for values greater than the mean and less than the mean: `med_high = signal[signal > signal.mean()].median()` and `med_low = signal[signal < signal.mean()].median()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an elaboration of the idea I put in my comment.

Use the mean of the signal as a threshold value. Then compute the median value for the parts of the signal that are above the threshold, and for those below. Use these to transform your data.

```
med_high = signal[signal > signal.mean()].median()
med_low = signal[signal < signal.mean()].median()
print (med_low, med_high)

new_signal = signal.transform(lambda x: med_low if x < signal.mean() else med_high)
plt.figure(figsize = (7,3))
plt.plot(new_signal, color = "firebrick")
plt.axhline(0.5, linestyle = ":")
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]